# Milk from a worshipped cow

Tags: avodah-zarah, parts-of-the-body, dairy, masecheth-avodah-zarah

The gemara in [Avodah Zarah 34b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Avodah_Zarah.34b.13-14?lang=bi) brings the shitta of Rav Achdevoi who holds that if one wants to be mekudeshes with intestinal fluid from a calf that was worshipped then the person is not mekudeshes.

Do we consider milk from a cow which was worshipped for avodah zarah the same as intestinal fluid?

Comment: Isn't the cow itself muttar (for eating, I assume you mean)? Why are you asking about the milk?

Comment: @double AA its becomes a neevad which is assur behaana

Comment: @DoubleAA, those who worship cows (only Hindus AFAIK) do not eat them, however they consume their milk. If so, the milk might be different, as far as I know, it is one of the causes for their cattle veneration.

Comment: @Nafkamina That's not true. It's just asur al gabei mizbeach.

Comment: @DoubleAA no, a davar ne'evad is assur behana'a - If you sell it, the money must be destroyed (I believe the Talmud suggests throwing it into the sea...)

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky That's not true. It's just asur al gabei mizbeach.

Comment: I'm not sure it is the cow itself that is worshiped by hindus. Horses and other animals ar not killed or mutilated; this is not actually 'worship' of the animals. Its more like letting living things live honouring life.

Answer (score 2):

That would depend on how connected the milk inside the udders is to the cow. Conceptually, a kosher, slaughtered cow with milk in it's udders can be cooked and eaten with that milk de'oraysa, [but may be assur midirabannan](http://www.dafdigest.org/Chulin/Chullin%20109.pdf). That implies we view the milk as still incorporated with the cow.

Therefore, if the cow becomes assur, the milk in it's udders is assur as well. (This is essential to the [issue/debate](http://kosherpoint.com/what-can-be-wrong-with-that/is-milk-kosher/) with modern milk, btw.) If it was milked before it became assur, we can safely assume the milk came from a kosher animal, even though that animal is presently assur.

Comment: Isn't the milk kosher if a jew was milking the cow or if a jew was present at the time of milking?

Comment: @gamliela that's only true if the animal itself were permissible to eat, and a cow used for idol worship is forbidden.

Comment: ah, makes sense.